# Is it possible to assign a function to an object in case of calling the object?

Tags: javascript

I have a type of objects called action. They are constructed like this:

```
const Action = (name, type, cb) => ({
   name,
   type,
   do: cb
})

const dumbtion = Action('dumb', 'system', () => { console.log("I'm dumb")})
```

It can satisfy my needs however I prefer to use `dumbtion()` instead of `dumbtion.do()`. Is there anyway to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: So where will the other properties go?

Comment: I dont understand what `name` and `type` are supposed to do

Comment: Should `name` and `type` be eradicated?

Comment: You *could* do that `dumbtion = () => { console.log("I'm dumb")}` but you lose access to the properties. Or you could store those by making a curried function but it's not really clear what your use case is here.

Comment: Actions are building blocks of my system and they serve some complex task such as logging and access-control. Action is a fairly complex function I just simplified it because I thought that complexity is irrelevant to the question. Properties serving very important purpose in system and I need to access them whenever I want. They are working well but I'm very unhappy with .do() syntax. I guess the solution must be in something like macros but I just found sweet.js that brings macros to javascript and I really don't want to add a new complexity level to my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `closure` and return a new function that when run will call `cb` with `name` and `type` as parameters.

```js
function createAction(name, type, cb) {
  return function() {
    cb(name, type);
  };
}

const dumbtion = createAction('dumb', 'system', (name, type) => {
  console.log(`I'm '${name}' of type: '${type}'`);
});

dumbtion();
```

If you also want to access those properties (with different names, since `name` is an existing property of `Function`) you could do :

```js
function createAction(name, type, cb) {
  const result = function() {
    return cb(result._name, result._type);
  };
  result._name = name;
  result._type = type;
  return result;
}

const dumbtion = createAction('dumb', 'system', (name, type) => {
  console.log(`I'm '${name}' of type: '${type}'`);
});

dumbtion();

dumbtion._name = "not dumb";
dumbtion._type = "not system";

dumbtion();
```

Though you will have more control if using `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
function createAction(name, type, cb) {
  const result = function() {
    return cb(name, type);
  };
  Object.defineProperty(result, "_name", {
    get: function() {
      return name;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      name = value;
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(result, "_type", {
    get: function() {
      return type;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      type = value;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const dumbtion = createAction('dumb', 'system', (name, type) => {
  console.log(`I'm '${name}' of type: '${type}'`);
});

dumbtion();

dumbtion._name = "not dumb";
dumbtion._type = "not system";

dumbtion();
```

Comment: Oh this is so good. I guess I will use this to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible*, by assigning the properties directly to the function, and then returning the function:

```js
const Action = (actionName, type, cb) => (
  Object.assign(cb, { actionName, type })
)
const dumbtion = Action('dumb', 'system', () => { console.log("I'm dumb")})

dumbtion();
console.log(dumbtion.type);
```

But that's not a good idea - functions generally shouldn't have non-standard properties added to them. I prefer the code you're currently using.

(note that the property `name` can't be used, because that's reserved on functions - it can't be reassigned)

Answer (score 1):

You can have `Action` return a function that *closes over* the parameters `name` and `type`:

```js
const Action = (name, type, cb) => () => cb(name, type);

const dumbtion = Action('dumb', 'system', (name, type) => {
    console.log(`I'm dumb, name = ${name}, type = ${type}`);
});

dumbtion();
```

`Action` doesn't really serve much purpose in that specific example, but the general pattern is fairly useful.

If you want access to `name` and `type` on `dumbtion` itself, functions are objects, so you can add properties to them:

```js
const Action = (xname, type, cb) => {
  cb.xname = xname;
  cb.type = type;
  return cb;
};

const dumbtion = Action('dumb', 'system', function cb() {
    console.log(`I'm dumb, name = ${cb.xname}, type = ${cb.type}`);
});

dumbtion();
console.log(dumbtion.xname);
console.log(dumbtion.type);
```

Notice I used a named function expression there so that the callback could access itself by name within the call. Also note that you can't use `name`, it's a predefined property of functions. (Well, okay, you *could* use it via `Object.defineProperty`, but better not to.)

Comment: Actions are building blocks of my system and they serve some complex task such as logging and access-control. Action is a fairly complex function I just simplified it because I thought that complexity is irrelevant to the question. Properties serving very important purpose in system and I need to access them outside of the function as well. So I can not use the first solution.

Comment: However I guess the second solution works but @CertainPerformance told in an answer : "But that's not a good idea - functions generally shouldn't have non-standard properties added to them." and I don't know why because I'm not that good javascript developer. I guess the solution must be in something like macros but I just found sweet.js that brings macros to javascript and I really don't want to add a new complexity level to my system.

Comment: @AjandMardalizad - The statement that functions "shouldn't" have non-standard properties is an opinion. Doing it is perfectly valid and well-specified. You do need to use names that are unlikely to collide with properties functions may get in the future. You might consider a single property with a very project-specific name which refers to an object with the other properties, so `cb.projectName.name` and `cb.projectName.type`, etc. But functions have only gotten one new property in years (`name`), and they already had it on most platforms, it was just standardized.

Answer (score 1):

An object that isn't a function can't be treated as one.

You can create a function and assign the properties to that instead.

```js
const action = (name, type, cb) => {
   const func = function () {
       return cb.apply(this, arguments);
   };
   func.name = name;
   func.type = type;
   func.do = cb;
   return func;
};

const modified = action('a name', 'system', () => { console.log("Foo")})

modified();
console.log(modified.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return a `function` from your `Action` function, which calls `.do` under the hood:

```
const Action = (name, type, cb) => () => ({
   name,
   type,
   do: cb
}).do();

const dumbtion = Action('dumb', 'system', () => { console.log("I'm dumb")})

dumbtion(); // <-- calls `.do()` internally
```

But you'll loose the possibility to access the other properties then.